# Gnuplot script, for loop within or adding to existing plot

Tags: gnuplot

I would like to plot a series of vertical lines in gnuplot at a set interval.

Some information about the plot.

The plot is mainly some data from a .dat file. The gnuplot script is called by a bash scripts which alters the gnu plot script using sed. This is a snipit of the an old bash script (ugly I'm sure).

```
sed -i 's/C = CONCEHOLD/C = '${$CO}'/g' $GNUPLOTROOT/plotviscosity.plt
gnuplot $GNUPLOTROOT/plotviscosity.plt
mv my-plot.ps $VISCPLOTNAME
sed -i 's/C = '${$CO}'/C = CONCEHOLD/g' $GNUPLOTROOT/plotviscosity.plt
```

with the . plt file looking like this.

```
set title "Viscosity vs Time, C = CONCEHOLD, beta = RATHOLD, zeta = ZETAHOLD"
set xlabel "Time"
set ylabel "Viscosity"
plot "viscout.dat" using 3:2 title 'Viscosity'
# Saving to my-plot.ps
load save.plt
#
```

I would like to add to this plot a series of vertical lines at a set repeating interval. I have found how to plot vertical lines via [http://t16web.lanl.gov/Kawano/gnuplot/parametric-e.html](http://web.archive.org/web/20110716113337/http://t16web.lanl.gov/Kawano/gnuplot/parametric-e.html)

```
set parametric
const=3
set trange [1:4]
set xrange [0:5]
set yrange [0:5]
plot const,t
```

I would like to have

```
const=repititionperiod*i
```

where i is an integer belonging to (1,calculateduppedlimit].

I could input repititionperiod via sed again and in a similar vain calculateduppedlimit but need some sort of for loop either within gnuplot or a separate gnuplot script that adds a vertical line to the already created plot within a for loop in my bash script.

I can't find any information on loops within gnu plot or adding to a previously created plot.

Any advice gratefully received.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:** Gnuplot does now in fact now support a for loop,  you can read about it [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20110716113337/http://t16web.lanl.gov/Kawano/gnuplot/index-e.html)

As I understand gnuplot doesn't have a for loop, although you can generate one of sorts as follows:

Make a file "loop.gp" containing

```
const  = const + 1
#... some gnuplot commands ... 
if(const<100) reread
```

then in a gnuplot terminal, or script write,

```
const = 3; load "loop.gp";
```

This will give you a simple loop.

(this example is taken from the misc. section of [http://t16web.lanl.gov/Kawano/gnuplot/index-e.html](http://web.archive.org/web/20110716113337/http://t16web.lanl.gov/Kawano/gnuplot/index-e.html))

For your particular answer you might try adding arrows rather than paremetric lines,
eg.

```
set arrow from const,1 to const,4 nohead
```

will do much the same thing.

In this case you loop.gp could be

```
const  = const + repititionperiod
#... some gnuplot commands ...  
set arrow from const,1 to const,4 nohead
if(const<calculatedupperlimit) reread
```

and you would run you loop with

```
const = 1; repititionperiod=2;calculatedupperlimit = 10; load "loop.gp"; replot;
```

The replot plots the arrows.

If you "just" want the lines and nothing else - then you will need to feed a graph to actually plot (a set of arrows doesn't count).  The example you gave could then be used to plot the first vertical line.

hope this helps.

Tom