# How do I convert an integer to a string in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I know how to use `$` with `using` in examples like

```
plot datafile using f($1):g($2)
```

to plot functions of column data. But I want to use this feature in a loop:

```
plot for [c=1:10] datafile using f($(c)):g($(c+1))
```

Of course this code doesn't work. I guess that if I know how to convert the integer `c` to a string (or a single ASCII character) then it would work. How can I do it?

(If the same task can be done without conversion of integer to string, that would be fine too.)

Comment: Not sure what your placeholder c means? If you want a for loop in gnuplot try something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062999/gnuplot-script-for-loop-within-or-adding-to-existing-plot/4115145#4115145.  If you want to split the output depending on the xrange use the ternary operator http://t16web.lanl.gov/Kawano/gnuplot/misc1-e.html

Comment: I don't think that gnuplot thinks of _c_ as a string. It rather parses the line and sees that 'c' is not a number and then breaks the interpretation, since this works:
plot for [c=2:3] datafile using (f($1)):(g($2)) title sprintf("%d", c)
Note that _c_ is interpreted as an integer in the end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you looking for something like:

```
plot for [c=1:5] datafile using (column(c)):(column(c+1))
```

This will do: `plot datafile u 1:2, "" u 2:3, "" u 3:4, "" u 4:5, "" u 5:6`

Comment: Coming back after a long time... and that's exactly what I wanted :).  Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

You can Use intrinsic function sprintf to convert numbers to string

```
gnuplot>  a=3; b=6;
gnuplot>  plot a*x+b title sprintf("a=%1.2f; b=%1.2f",a,b)
```

Comment: This is the only answer that is consistent with the title of the question!

Answer (score 0):

```
set title sprintf("Polinômio de Taylor no ponto %f ",a)
```

or the English variant

```
set title sprintf("Taylor Polynomial at the point %f ",a)
```

will define the title transforming the number a into the previous string
I have use this in a loop, with the Taylor Polynomial calculated previously
at the point a, where a  containing  a number is the governing variable of the while.

Answer (score -1):

How about something like this? The loop statement could be different depending on the shell you are using. The one below is using bash.

```
plot '< for i in 1 2 3 4 ; do echo $i ; done' us ($1):($1+1)
```

Answer (score -1):

Prepend an empty string if necessary. E.g.:

```
gnuplot> a=42
gnuplot> print a." questions"
         internal error : STRING operator applied to non-STRING type

gnuplot> print "".a." questions"
42 questions
```

The first `print` fails because of a type mismatch. The second one works fine though. Apparently `.` is left associative.