# Auto plotting all columns

Tags: gnuplot

I have a file with several columns of data (the number of columns N might me quite large). I want to plot all the columns as a function of the first one (that is, *plot 'Data.txt' using 1:2, 'Data.txt' using 1:3, ..., 'Data.txt' using 1:N*). The thing is, I want this command to work when I don't know the number of columns. Is that possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can count the number of columns in your file using `awk` and then do a looped plot. There might be a function to get the number of columns in your data file already implemented in gnuplot but I do not know it. You can try this:

```
N=`awk 'NR==1 {print NF}' Data.txt`
plot for [i=2:N] "Data.txt" u 1:i
```

If your first row contains a comment (starting by `#`) change `NR==` to the appropriate value. If you have a variable number of columns for different rows then you might want to complicate the `awk` command.

Answer (score 3):

@Paul shows a correct answer, but an even simpler variant is possible. You can use an open-ended iteration that stops when it runs out of columns:

```
plot for [n=1:*] "data.dat" using 1:n title sprintf("Column %d",n)
```

Answer (score 2):

Seeing that this questions is very old, I still think it is worth revisiting, as you now (Version 5.2) have access to the number of columns in a file without relying on external tools.

```
DATA = 'path/to/datafile.txt'
stats DATA
```

will (among other stuff) store the number of columns in the variable `STATS_columns`, so now you can do something like:

```
N=STATS_columns
plot for [i=2:N] DATA using 1:i title DATA.' '.i with lines
```

which will plot all the columns (assuming the first column is used for the x-axis) with legend entries matching the filename plus the column number.

PS: Not sure when this feature was introduced, but it's there now. :)

Answer (score 1):

You will need two script files:

```
==== main.plt ====
set <whatever>
N=1
load "loop.plt"

==== loop.plt ====
replot "data.dat" u 0:(column(N))
N+=N+1
if(N<4) reread
```

Function `reread` cause that the next line to read by gp will be `loop.plt:1`. Now you will plot first three columns of `data.dat`. Function `replot` adds plot to current image.

**Or see: [how to convert integer to string in gnuplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5242253/how-to-convert-integer-to-string-in-gnuplot).**

Comment: But that won't count you the number of columns in your data file.